# I need some help optimizing my database schema

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, database-design

Here's a layout of my data:

```
Heading 1:
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading

Heading 2:
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading

Heading 3:
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading

Heading 4:
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading

Heading 5:
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
   Sub heading
```

These headings need to have a 'Completion Status' boolean value which gets linked to a user Id.

Currently, this is how my table looks:

```
id  |  userID  |  field_1  |  field_2  |  field_3  |  field_4  | etc...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |     1    |    0      |     0     |     1     |     0     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2   |     2    |    1      |     0     |     1     |     1     |
```

Each field represents one Sub Heading. Having this many columns in my table looks awfully inefficient...

How can I go about optimizing this? I can't think of any way to neaten it up :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use boolean values but simple relations:

**`table completion_status`**

```
id user_id field_id

1  1       3
2  2       1
3  2       3
4  2       4
...
```

From that it's easy to see that user 1 has completed field 3, and user 2 fields 1, 3 and 4.

This way you don't have to change your database schema whenever you want to change the amount of fields.

Comment: I was using a similar method to begin with but the table ended up having 27 rows for the one user. This number will likely grow in the future. Is this not bad? Shouldn't I try to limit the table size as much as possible?

Comment: Yup. But this way, you only use the rows that have data - your way, you have lots of unused columns. Also, imagine having to add a new type - this way it's a blink of an eye - your way would involve changing the table and the queries.

Comment: i don't think having multiple rows for the same user is a problem. modern DBMS can handle millions of rows without issues. just make sure that you add proper indexes.

Comment: No, this is not bad, as long as you define proper indices. Have a look at [this Wikipedia article on first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Comment: @Steffan, the amount of rows does not have any significance in your case. Actually this way you end up _saving_ space as in your example all users have all the fields defined either 0 or 1. With my proposed solution, users' fields will only take as much space as minimally required.

Comment: I'll change up my structure. Thanks for the help :}

Comment: @Steffan, don't forget to mark the answer accepted so others don't have to bother any more :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have the sub-headings in a different table, and then link that table to the first table.

```
id  |  userID  |  field_id | 
-----------------------------
1   |     1    |    0      | 
-----------------------------
2   |     2    |    1      |
```

where table `field` looks like this

```
id  | field_1 | field_2   | etc..
-----------------------------
1   |     1   |    0      | etc..
```

Comment: That doesn't really change anything, just splits the data into two tables. The problem with too many columns still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you make a table like this?

```
id  | User Id | Field ID | Status
---------------------------------
1   |   1     |   1      | 0   
2   |   1     |   2      | 1
```

You can have another master table for Fields with the field names

Comment: No need for `status`, if the `field_id` exists, it's done, otherwise it's not.

Comment: Well, if you decide to add an "in-progress" status later, this will help. :)